# $\sup(c+A) = c + \sup A$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation, self-learning

Let $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be bounded above and let $c \in \mathbb
{R}$. Define the set $c + A = \{c + a : a \in A\} $

Now since $a \leq \sup A , \forall a\in A$. Then $a + c \leq \sup A + c $. So $A+c$ has an upper bound. Now the claim is that $\sup(c+A) = c + \sup A.$

So now I have to prove that $\forall \varepsilon> 0, c+a > c + \sup A - \varepsilon.$

How can I proceed? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wish to use $\varepsilon$s instead, suppose $\varepsilon > 0$. I claim that $c + \sup A - \varepsilon$ is **not** and upper bound for $c + A$. Since you have proven that $c + \sup A$ is an upper bound for $c + A$, this would mean that no lesser number than $c + \sup A$ can be an upper bound of $c + A$. That is $c + \sup A$ is the supremum of $c + A$.

To prove this claim, it suffices to find some $x \in c + A$ such that $x > c + \sup A - \varepsilon$.

Note that, since $\sup A$ is the least upper bound for $A$, it follows that $\sup A - \varepsilon$ is **not** an upper bound for $A$. Therefore, there must be some $a \in A$ such that
$$a > \sup A - \varepsilon.$$
Adding $c$ to both sides,
$$c + a > c + \sup A - \varepsilon.$$
Note that $c + a \in c + A$ by definition of $c + A$. Hence, we can choose $x = c + a$, and our proof of the claim is complete.

Answer (score 2):

You have shown that $c + \sup A$ is an upper bound to $c + A$, and hence $\sup(c + A) \le c + \sup A$. Replacing $A$ with $c + A$ and $c$ with $-c$, we obtain
$$\sup(-c + (c + A)) \le -c + \sup(c + A) \le -c + c + \sup A = \sup A.$$
Now, note that $A \subseteq -c + (c + A)$, as if $x \in A$, then $c + x \in c + A$, and so $x = -c + (c + x) \in -c + (c + A)$. Therefore,
$$\sup A \le \sup(-c + (c + A)).$$
Putting this together with the above inequalities, we see that all the inequalities must be equality, by the antisymmetry of $\le$. Hence,
$$-c + \sup(c + A) = \sup A \implies \sup(c + A) = c + \sup A.$$

Comment: can we do this by taking different cases for epsilon like when epsilon is less than c and when epsilon is gtreater than c?

Comment: There shouldn't be any need to split into cases. Note that $c + a > c + \sup A - \varepsilon$, is equivalent to $a > \sup A - \varepsilon$. For any $\varepsilon > 0$, such an $a \in A$ exists (or else $\sup A - \varepsilon$ is a lesser upper bound than $\sup A$). Hence, $a + c \in c + A$ is such that $a + c > c + \sup A - \varepsilon$.

Comment: third line of your comment is not quite clear to me

Comment: @J.Deff As in, everything after "Hence..."?

Comment: yes............also your proof is non intuitive, is their any central idea of your answer which i fail to grasp, although i understand it?

Comment: Let me explain the intuition behind my answer. Taking $A$ and producing $c + A$ is the process of shifting $A$ to the right along the number line by $c$ units. For example, if $A = [2, 4]$, then $7 + A = [9, 11]$. Naturally we expect the supremum to shift along with it (which you were on your way to proving). You showed that the supremum might be what we expect, or lesser. So, shifting might make the supremum less than expected. But, a shift by $-c$ will undo a shift by $c$! Doing the two shifts can only make the supremum lesser, even though they cancel each other to produce $A$!

Comment: As for my comment, recall $a \in A$ was constructed in the previous sentence, and so (straight from the definition of $c + A$) we have $c + a \in c + A$. Our $a$ satisfied $a > \sup A - \varepsilon$, hence adding $c$ to both sides, $a + c > c + \sup A - \varepsilon$.

Comment: in you second last line of second last comment, shouldnt it be a+ c shift instead of a shift?

Comment: so this explains why you changed the inequality

Comment: When I say "a shift", I'm talking about one shift. The "a" is the indefinite article, not a variable. If wanted to refer to the variable, I would write "$a$-shift", or "a shift by $a$".

Comment: but epsilon proof will also work for this question ? no?

Comment: why dont we do it this way. we have to prove that c + Sup A \leq sup (c + A). if we change $c \ to -c and A to A +c to sup(c + A) \leq c + sup A$. we will get our iequality. whats the need to do  the rest of the proof

Comment: @J.Deff I'm having trouble reading your last comment.

Comment: just changing c to -c and A to A + c in first line will get to equality i mean

Comment: "can we do this by taking different cases for epsilon like when epsilon is less than c and when epsilon is gtreater than c?"  $\epsilon$ has *nothing* whatsoever to do with $c$.  $\epsilon$ is arbitrarily close to $0$ whether we are dealing with values in $A$ or values in $c + A$.  There is an $a \in A$ so that $a > \sup A - \epsilon$ then just adding $c$ will give us $c + a > c+\sup A - \epsilon$.  The $\epsilon$ has nothing to do with $c$.

Answer (score 1):

> So now I have to prove that ∀ε>0,c+a>c+supA−ε.

Well if that *is* what you have to prove, then you'd have $\forall \epsilon > 0, a > \sup A - \epsilon$ so $c+a > c +\sup A - \epsilon$.

But I think you meant $\forall \epsilon >0 \exists a \in A$ so $a > \sup A - \epsilon$, and so for that $a$, $c+a\in c+A$ and $c+a > c+\sup A - \epsilon$.

Basically everything you can say about the set $A$, its elements and any bounds, can be said about $c + A$ by adding $c$ to all pertainent parts.

Comment: thanks...............